# onPress event is not working in react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-stylesheet

I've been trying to add **onPress** event on buttons in my page but it's not responding and since I'm new to react native I couldn't figure it out.

This is the code of the page I want to put **onPress** event in:

```
const HomeMenu = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Tile
                    imageSrc={require('../../assets/images/homeMenu.jpg')}
                    title="Which property are you looking for?"
                    contentContainerStyle={{ height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#21534A', alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 0.5 }}
                    titleStyle={styles.title}

                    containerStyle={{ height: '45%' }}

                >

                    <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.categoryBtn} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <View style={styles.categoryIcon}>
                                <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/house.png')} style={styles.categoryImg}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>Residential</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.categoryBtn} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <View style={styles.categoryIcon}>
                                <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/store.png')} style={styles.categoryImg}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>Commercial</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.categoryBtn} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <View style={styles.categoryIcon}>
                                <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/real-estate.png')} style={styles.categoryImg}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>All</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.categoryBtn} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <View style={styles.categoryIcon}>
                                <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/industry.png')} style={styles.categoryImg}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>Industrial</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.categoryBtn} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <View style={styles.categoryIcon}>
                                <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/region.png')} style={styles.categoryImg}></Image>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>Lands</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('Pressed...')}>
                            <Text style={{ color: "#FFFFFF", alignItems: 'center', textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}> Looking for an agency?</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>

                </Tile>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

I'm thinking that the reason why it's not responding to **onPress** event is because of the design but I'm not sure.
If you needed any more information to post to help you solve my issue let me know please.

Comment: It seems like a normal codebase. But, how can you check the `console` to confirm `onPress` did not work?

Comment: I tried to check the condole first to avoid future errors and the console didn't work with me, is it a good idea to do that or I shouldn't check the console first?

Comment: for me, some time it happens when i select auto import after starting to type when my code editor suggest, and it accidently imported from other place instead of 'react-native', can you please check if TouchableOpacity is imported from 'react-native' and not from other place, in my case it was imported from 'react-native-gesture-....something'

Comment: yes I checked and it's imported from 'react-native', should i change it to 'react-native-gesture'? @Nikhilbhatia

Answer (score 1):

The problems comes form **Tiles** component. Tiles like Cards, are a convenient way to display related content about a **single subject**. You can't have pressable components inside Tile. Try to use [Card](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/card) component from same lib.